# What is a very simple method to predict a value that happens after a serie of values

Tags: sequences-and-series

Im creating a website about Universities , and they usually have a threshold for accepting students each year , it usually depends on the numbers of seats available , the number of contestants ...etc

What im trying to do is predict the next threshhold based only on the previous threshholds .

For example : the thresholds for the previous years are the following in order : 14 , 14.5 , 16 , 15.25.

What is the simplest way to predict the next one based on the way the treshholds were going up and down?

I'm very close to the deadline and I have just realized ( thanks to the folks here ) that my previous method only used the first and last threshhold . Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can use finite difference extrapolation method.

Comment: Im not familiar with that method since both my english and knowledge are limited , do I google that ?
Edit : googling it did not help

Comment: You can try googling " polynomial interpolation"

Comment: "linear regression" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Fitting_the_regression_line